# ASP.Net: GridView control and combobox woes part 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a follow up to: [ASP.Net: GridView control and combobox woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637920/asp-net-gridview-control-and-combobox-woes)

I've implemented my code as kd7 has answered but I'm getting a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I've simplified the code as follows:

Event handler for the button click:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["MyKey"] = "Test";
}
```

The Page_Load now has:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = ViewState["MyKey"].ToString();
    }
}
```

**My question is:** Why is ViewState["MyKey"] coming back as null and causing a NullReference exception?

**Please note that the code above is only a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. Please see the previous question given in the first line of this question to see full details.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Because in the asp page lifecycle the page load is called before the postback event is executed.

How about: -

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDisplay.Text = "Test";
}
```

Comment: No because, the code is only a sample to help me do something else. I need to be able to grab the value from a combobox that the user as selected from and process that value in the Page_Load event.

Comment: Then why didn't you ask the question you wanted answering? And why vote me down for correctly answering the question you asked?

Comment: To be fair, my question was why I was getting a NullReferenceException. Your reply didn't answer this which is why I voted it down. My first line did mention this was a follow up to the previous question (which contained all the details) and I mentioned that I simplified the code. This is why I voted down your answer as it was incorrect.

Comment: ViewState["MyKey"] is coming back as null and causing a NullReference exception because the page_load event is executed *before* the button submit event therefore the Viewstate["MyKey"] has not yet been set. This is in my answer. As for what you're trying to do, the original answer is ok, other than there's no need to set and use viewstate: let .Net do it for you on the combobox (enableviewstate=true) and just take the combobox selectedvalue directly on postback.

Answer (score 0):

The NullReferenceException might be related to the fact that you are trying to get the ViewState["MyKey"] value before you have set it. Try validating first:

```
if (ViewState["MyKey"] != null)
{
    txtDisplay.Text = ViewState["MyKey"].ToString();
}
else
{
    //manage the situation accordingly
}
```

Hope this helps!